# SSH access to Ec2 instance timed out in landing zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-iot

My Setup,

1. i added my ip address in inbound rules of security group
2. access key is connected properly to ec2 and locally i given enough permission to the key while ssh
3. i saw the ec2 instance connected to public subnet
4. public subnet is connect to internet gateway which opens the path to internet

Important Notes:

1. if i set the inbound rules to 0.0.0.0 in security group i can able to ssh into my instance but not able to ssh with my ip address
2. i checked my indian friends and added their ip address interesting part is they can able to access

**Can someone help me where is the restriction comes i tried all my possibilities not able to fix this**

Comment: I think that problem is only in your IP address. Check it twice at https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and try once more time to add it to the security group.

Comment: i tried from the same web site.. beleive me i tried all my best moves before coming here..i checked ip address, routing table, vpc, security group..
interesting part is why indian guy ip address access it why not finland guy ip adrdress not accessing .. is there any glocal level restriction ??

Comment: Could you try to connect via mobile phone? I mean have you tried to connect from different device via different internet provider? Maybe the are some restrictions in your router/provider etc.

Comment: tested with my mobile internet as well also wife device facing same issue.. not checked with outside guys..